# MaxMetaspaceSize=3072m and MaxHeap Size=11g and HeapSize=1024m and still out of memory:Metaspace

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm, out-of-memory, metaspace

I have set MaxMetaspaceSize to 3072m;  MaxHeap Size=11g and HeapSize=1024m.

Can anyone suggest what is problem with this settings on server

```
-d64 -XX:ThreadStackSize=256m -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=3072m
```

We usually get Metaspace issue and we restart the Wildfly server everytime; but after 6 hours we get metaspace again.

There are 40 projects deployed which are using these setting. (Each project has around 5 to 10 classes only) and mostly are schedulers (Connect DB and create file to SFTP OR hit Rest api and update some DB).

Mostly fire once during night and a few fire in like 30 minutes. In one integration, we need to load 2,00,000 data in memory and integration runs fine.

Is there issue in metaspace settings? Should i increase?
[image]

Comment: This symptom is consistent with a memory leak. I would take a heap dump and analyze if I were you, to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: Go through all options and ask yourself about each “Do I actually know what it does and why it has been specified for my application?” and if not, remove it. Afterwards, run the software again and if encountering a problem then, ask a question.